# MeshLab error: "Require same number of chosen points"

Tags: 3d, alignment, meshlab

I'm trying to align two different 3d scanned objects together using MeshLab.

I started by choosing the first mesh and clicked on "Glue Mesh Here". Then, I clicked on the second mesh and selected "Point Base Glueing".

After I tried aligning them, I kept on receiving this error: "Require same number of chosen points"

Do you have any idea about how to fix this error?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should pick at least four corresponding points on each point cloud.Maybe [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4g9Hap4rX0k) will be helpful.

Comment: Thanks! the is exactly what I've been looking for